# How do I convert an Excel serial date number to a .NET DateTime?

Tags: .net, excel, datetime

How do I convert from excel serial date to a .NET date time?

For example  39938 is 05/05/2009.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Where 39938 is the number of days since 1/1/1900?

**In that case, use the framework library function [`DateTime.FromOADate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) .**
This function [encapsulates](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,548) all the specifics, and does bounds checking.

For its historical value, here is a possible implementation:

(C#)

```cs
public static DateTime FromExcelSerialDate(int SerialDate)
{
    if (SerialDate > 59) SerialDate -= 1; //Excel/Lotus 2/29/1900 bug   
    return new DateTime(1899, 12, 31).AddDays(SerialDate);
}
```

VB

```vb
Public Shared Function FromExcelSerialDate(ByVal SerialDate As Integer) As DateTime
    If SerialDate > 59 Then SerialDate -= 1 ' Excel/Lotus 2/29/1900 bug
    Return New DateTime(1899, 12, 31).AddDays(SerialDate)
End Function
```

---

**[Update]:**
Hmm... A quick test of that shows it's actually two days off.  Not sure where the difference is.

Okay: problem fixed now. See the comments for details.

Comment: I know 1 day is for Lotus having a bug about 02/29/1900 it had it as a day that doesn't exist.  I don't know what the other day is.

Comment: VBA dates (Excel) start at 12/30/1899

Comment: It works if you subtract 2, but it fails for serial dates of at least below 60 (02/29/1900) and the second sneak day in there.

Comment: I think you get 2 days too much with this conversion, i.e. the epoch date would have to be moved back to DateTime(1899, 12, 30). This is due to Excel's leap year bug I assume.

Comment: Oops, everyone else was faster ;-) And yes, the bug originally comes from Lotus as Joel explained: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

Comment: You also need to do a check for any number under 60, if it is under 60 do not subtract 1 because you are not in the bug yet.  If it is over you must subtract one from the date because of the 02/29/1900 bug.

Comment: Wow, even a fix for the first to months of the beginning of time (in Excel universe) is included! Impressed :-)

Comment: You add to 12/31/1899, so that 1/1/1900 is day #1 rather than day #0.  After that it's the Lotus leap year thing.

Comment: -1 for duplicating what is already solved in the .NET Framework (DateTime.FromOADate).

Comment: For more info on FromOADate, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx

Comment: While I agree that the FROMOADate method is better, I still found this answer informative.

Comment: Wonderful solution by Joel Coehoorn. It also saved my lot of time.

Comment: Another thing that's worth mentioning is that it's possible to have an Excel file that uses **1/1/1904** as a starting date instead of the above expected _1/1/1900_. This can be set with **MS Excel -> Options -> Advanced -> Use 1904 date system**. For more info see [Differences between the 1900 and the 1904 date system in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system).

Answer (score 203):

I find it simpler using [FromOADate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx), for example:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(39938);
```

Using this code *dt* is "05/05/2009".

Comment: This also handles dates with time values (floating point in the underlying data format), which the accepted solution does not.

Comment: @nullptr However, it has a precision of only 1 millisecond. You can get a much higher precision if you care. See [my answer elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13922172/1336654).

Comment: For my PowerShell peepz: `[DateTime]::FromOADate($serialDate)`

Answer (score 2):

For 39938 do this:
 39938 * 864000000000 + 599264352000000000

864000000000 represents number of ticks in a day
599264352000000000 represents number of ticks from the year 0001 to the year 1900

Answer (score 1):

```
void ExcelSerialDateToDMY(int nSerialDate, int &nDay, 
                          int &nMonth, int &nYear)
{
    // Excel/Lotus 123 have a bug with 29-02-1900. 1900 is not a
    // leap year, but Excel/Lotus 123 think it is...
    if (nSerialDate == 60)
    {
        nDay    = 29;
        nMonth    = 2;
        nYear    = 1900;

        return;
    }
    else if (nSerialDate < 60)
    {
        // Because of the 29-02-1900 bug, any serial date 
        // under 60 is one off... Compensate.
        nSerialDate++;
    }

    // Modified Julian to DMY calculation with an addition of 2415019
    int l = nSerialDate + 68569 + 2415019;
    int n = int(( 4 * l ) / 146097);
            l = l - int(( 146097 * n + 3 ) / 4);
    int i = int(( 4000 * ( l + 1 ) ) / 1461001);
        l = l - int(( 1461 * i ) / 4) + 31;
    int j = int(( 80 * l ) / 2447);
     nDay = l - int(( 2447 * j ) / 80);
        l = int(j / 11);
        nMonth = j + 2 - ( 12 * l );
    nYear = 100 * ( n - 49 ) + i + l;
}
```

Cut and Paste of someone elses talents...

[Ian Brown](http://www.ianbrownphotography.co.uk)