# .NET DateTime, different resolution when converting to and from OADate?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, resolution, ole-automation

I'm converting a DateTime to OADate. I was expecting to get the exact same DateTime when converting the OADate back, but now it has only millisecond resolution, and is therefore different.

```
var a = DateTime.UtcNow;
double oadate = a.ToOADate();
var b = DateTime.FromOADate(oadate);
int compare = DateTime.Compare(a, b); 

//Compare is not 0; the date times are not the same
```

Ticks from a: 634202170964319073

Ticks from b: 634202170964310000

The OADate double: 40437.290467951389

What is the reason for this? The resolution of DateTime is clearly good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static method called by ToOADate clearly divides the ticks by 10000 and then stores the result in a long, thus removing any sub millisecond info

Does anyone know where to find the specs of the OADate format?

```
    private static double TicksToOADate(long value)
    {
        if (value == 0L)
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
        if (value < 0xc92a69c000L)
        {
            value += 0x85103c0cb83c000L;
        }
        if (value < 0x6efdddaec64000L)
        {
            throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_OleAutDateInvalid"));
        }
        long num = (value - 0x85103c0cb83c000L) / 0x2710L;
        if (num < 0L)
        {
            long num2 = num % 0x5265c00L;
            if (num2 != 0L)
            {
                num -= (0x5265c00L + num2) * 2L;
            }
        }
        return (((double)num) / 86400000.0);
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly specs, but this is worth a read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/eric-s-complete-guide-to-vt-date.aspx

Answer (score 16):

I think this is an excellent question. (I just discovered it.)

Unless you're operating with dates quite close to the year 1900, a `DateTime` will have a *higher* precision than an OA date. But for some obscure reason, the authors of the `DateTime` struct just **love** to truncate to the nearest whole millisecond when they convert between `DateTime` and something else. Needless to say, doing this throws away a lot of precision without good reason.

Here's a work-around:

```
static readonly DateTime oaEpoch = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);

public static DateTime FromOADatePrecise(double d)
{
  if (!(d >= 0))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); // NaN or negative d not supported

  return oaEpoch + TimeSpan.FromTicks(Convert.ToInt64(d * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay));
}

public static double ToOADatePrecise(this DateTime dt)
{
  if (dt < oaEpoch)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

  return Convert.ToDouble((dt - oaEpoch).Ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerDay;
}
```

Now, let's consider (from your question) the `DateTime` given by:

```
var ourDT = new DateTime(634202170964319073);
// .ToSting("O") gives 2010-09-16T06:58:16.4319073
```

The precision of any `DateTime` is 0.1 µs.

Near the date and time we're considering, the precision of an OA date is:

> `Math.Pow(2.0, -37.0)` days, or circa `0.6286` µs

We conclude that *in this region* a `DateTime` is more precise than an OA date by (just over) a factor six.

Let's convert `ourDT` to `double` using my extension method above

```
double ourOADate = ourDT.ToOADatePrecise();
// .ToString("G") gives 40437.2904679619
// .ToString("R") gives 40437.290467961888
```

Now, if you convert `ourOADate` back to a `DateTime` using the static `FromOADatePrecise` method above, you get

> `2010-09-16T06:58:16.4319072` (written with `"O"` format)

Comparing with the original, we see that the loss of precision is in this case 0.1 µs. We expect the loss of precision to be within ±0.4 µs since this interval has length 0.8 µs which is comparable to the 0.6286 µs mentioned earlier.

If we go the other way, starting with a `double` representing an OA date not too close to the year 1900, and *first* use `FromOADatePrecise`, and *then* `ToOADatePrecise`, then we get back to a `double`, and because the precision of the intermediate `DateTime` is superior to that of an OA date, we expect a perfect round-trip in this case. If, on the other hand, you use the BCL methods `FromOADate` and `ToOADate` in the same order, it is extremely improbable to get a good round-trip (unless the `double` we started with has a very special form).

Comment: And it used to be worse. Years ago I found a bug where sometimes dates would be rounded to the nearest millisecond wrong, and it could possibly induce an error of as much as two days. Fortunately I think that was eventually fixed.

Comment: Hi @Jeppe - Thanks for that excellent write up. How is the calculation `Math.Pow(2.0, -37.0) days, or circa 0.6286 µs` for OA Date derived? I fail to wrap my head around this :-)

Comment: @Martin Ba, The OLE Automation date is implemented as an IEEE double-precision (64-bit) binary floating-point number whose value is the number of days from midnight, 30 December 1899. Floating point means the number of bits available for the fractional part depends on how big the integer part of the number is. As you see above, the integer part in our example is 40437. As long as it is between 32768 and 65535, there will be 37 bits left for the fractional part, and the precision I mentioned holds.

Answer (score 1):

Probably has something to do with precision of the double, not the DateTime.

Comment: The converted double is 40437.290467951389, looks pretty precise, but you might be correct.

Comment: Yes, the double would be precise enough, but because of the way double is stored, there is not an exact representation of the datetime as a double.

Comment: @Ezombort It looks precise only because of the conversion factor between seconds and days. If you multiply the `double` you mention, by `24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0`, you will see only three decimals. An "arbitrary" `double` of this magnitude will show five decimals (or seven decimals if you display with `.ToString("R")`). So the full precision of a `double` is not utilized. See my new answer.