# From DateTime to Int ? (1 = 01/01/1900, Excel)

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert an Excel serial date number to a .NET DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727466/how-do-i-convert-an-excel-serial-date-number-to-a-net-datetime)

I would like to find an easy way to convert DateTime to Int where `01/01/1900` is 1  (which is used in Excel's xmls).

Comment: And how do timeslices count? In milliseconds? Seconds? ...

Comment: Use the opposite method, DateTime.ToOADate()

Comment: You may find your answer on this CodeProject Article link: [Excel serial date to Day, Month, Year and vise versa][1]: [1]:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2750/Excel-serial-date-to-Day-Month-Year-and-vise-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is my suggestion after compiling ideas from here above:

```
            private Nullable<int> ToInt1900ForExcel(DateTime DT)
    {
        if (DT.Ticks < 599266080000000000)//Below 1900-1-1, Excel has some problems representing dates, search it on the web.
            return null;
        if (DT.Ticks < 599317056000000000)//Excel reproduced a bug from Lotus for compatibility reasons, 29/02/1900 didn't actually exist.
            return (int)(DT.ToOADate()) - 1;
        return (int)(DT.ToOADate());
    }
```

or if you prefer (negative values and zero won't work fine in Excel)

```
           private int ToInt1900ForExcel(DateTime DT)
    {
        if (DT.Ticks < 599317056000000000)//Excel reproduced a bug from Lotus for compatibility reasons, 29/02/1900 didn't actually exist.
            return (int)(DT.ToOADate()) - 1;
        return (int)(DT.ToOADate());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a built-in conversion:

```
int excelDays = (int)(yourDate.ToOADate());
```

Beware that 0 is **not** 1/1/1900, it is 12/31/1899.  Screwy due to a shortcut taken by Lotus 123 programmers who were trying to avoid having to deal with leap year rules.  1900 wasn't a leap year.  Having to be compatible with Lotus was a requirement back when Excel started, *everybody* used Lotus 123 back then.  A good war story about this bug was written up by Joel Spolsky, the CEO of StackExchange in this [blog post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html).  Relevant part is "It's a bug in Excel!" I exclaimed.

Comment: Google "excel lotus bug" to see why this is not correct.

Comment: I just answered question as it is :)

Comment: That's not the SO way, is it?  I fixed it the SO way.

Comment: :) SO way is 'answer the question as the question is correctly asked'

Comment: I've tested this (ToOADate()) with a few date: in 9/9/2012 = 41161 correct, 5/5/1935 = 12909 correct, 1900/1/1 = 2, incorrect. In Excel it's 1. 31/12/1900 = 366 ... according to Windows Calendar, February 1900 had only 28 days so year 1900 must have had 365.