# Combining date with string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My table contains daily quantities for different products. In my query, I'm trying to convert date (`12/28/18`) to the Excel value equivalent (43,462) and then combine it with the product name (ABC).

I tried different versions of concatenate and CAST but seem to be missing something.

Expected output is `43642-ABC`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
CREATE TABLE t(d DATETIME, c VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO t(d,c) VALUES('12/28/18', 'ABC');

SELECT *, CONCAT(DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', d)+2,'-',c) AS result
FROM t
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f88b4a8a7b4f21381e56c05a3fd702ba)**

Output:

```
+----------------------+------+-----------+
|          d           |  c   |  result   |
+----------------------+------+-----------+
| 28/12/2018 00:00:00  | ABC  | 43462-ABC |
+----------------------+------+-----------+
```

---

Explanation why two was added to DATEDIFF's result: [Difference between datetime converts in MSExcel and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23760262/5070879)