# Date changed into number when i fetch value from excel

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, dataset

I have an excel file which contains a lot of fields. I use the dataset to store the data fetched from this excel file. In excel sheet I have a date column that is set to the correct format. But when retrieved, the format is changed to a number in the dataset..

I don't know the reason for this issue.

Excel Value: 01/12/2015, changed to 42016 in the dataset.

Any pointers to this issue will be appreciated.

My code is

```
  private static DataSet GetExcelDataAsDataSet(string path)
        {

            return GetExcelDataReader(path).AsDataSet();
        }

        private static IExcelDataReader GetExcelDataReader(string path)
        {
            FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


            IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

            var data = excelReader.ResultsCount;
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();


            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

            return excelReader;
        }
```

Comment: can you please provide the code snippet where the data from excel is populated into the dataset?

Comment: The reason is that you retrieve the values as their numeric representation of VBA, not as date values. But without your code we cannot advice how to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/727495/1468942) it's as easy as using:

```
public static DateTime FromExcelSerialDate(int SerialDate)
{
    if (SerialDate > 59) SerialDate -= 1; //Excel/Lotus 2/29/1900 bug   
    return new DateTime(1899, 12, 31).AddDays(SerialDate);
}
```

The number you are getting is the number of days passed since 1/1/1900 so that function is your answer :)

You can use as well `DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(NUMBER);` and I think it will work better as extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2622982/1468942).