# Invalid data when using ExcelLibrary in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I need to read the DateTime from a cell from a xls file, but the cell contents is invalid, instead of returning the contents as a date or string it returns a number.
The code to read the file:

```
using System.IO;
using ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet;

namespace XLSX_reader
{
   class Program
   {
       private static ExcelDocument XlsDocument { get; set; }
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            var inputStream = new     MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("d:\\Work\\Flexportal_Other\\Importers\\11-2016_Uitzendrapportage_SRS_Personeel_85873112442611460665848.xls"));
        XlsDocument = new ExcelDocument(inputStream, null);
        Cell cell1 = XlsDocument.GetCell(6, 4);
        XlsDocument.GetCell(5, 7);
        var date = ExcelDocument.ParseDateTime(cell1);
    }
  }
}
```

ExcellDocument class:

```
namespace XLSX_reader
{
    public class ExcelDocument
    {
        public ExcelDocument(MemoryStream stream, string sheetName = null)
        {
            Workbook = LoadWorkbook(stream);
            if (Workbook == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("err");
             }

             Worksheet = LoadWorksheet(sheetName);
        }
     public Worksheet LoadWorksheet(string sheetName = null)
    {
        if (Workbook == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "##(Load workbook before loading worksheets)(Open eerst een werkboek alvorens een werkblad te openen)##");
        }

        Worksheet = sheetName != null
            ? Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(ws => ws.SheetType == SheetType.Worksheet && ws.Name == sheetName)
            : Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(ws => ws.SheetType == SheetType.Worksheet);

        if (Worksheet == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("##noWorksheetLoaded##");
        }

        RowIndexMin = Worksheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex;
        RowIndexMax = Worksheet.Cells.LastRowIndex;
        _rowIndex = RowIndexMin - 1;

        return Worksheet;
    }
    public Cell GetCell(int row, int column)
    {
        return Worksheet.Cells[row, column];
    }
  }
 }
```

The xls looks like this:
[image]

And the reading of the cell looks like this:
[image]

So the outcome is 42443, not a date or anything.
Do you have any idea why this happens and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: See this for how Excel stores dates : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm Here's how to convert : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727466/how-do-i-convert-an-excel-serial-date-number-to-a-net-datetime

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores dates as numbers, specifically, the number of days since Jan 1 1900.
[Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214094)

> Excel stores all dates as integers and all times as decimal fractions.
>   With this system, Excel can add, subtract, or compare dates and times
>   just like any other numbers, and all dates are manipulated by using
>   this system.
>
> In this system, the serial number 1 represents 1/1/1900 12:00:00 a.m.
>   Times are stored as decimal numbers between .0 and .99999, where .0 is
>   00:00:00 and .99999 is 23:59:59. The date integers and time decimal
>   fractions can be combined to create numbers that have a decimal and an
>   integer portion. For example, the number 32331.06 represents the date
>   and time 7/7/1988 1:26:24 a.m.