# How to get the date in day month year from date value

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, epplus-4

I am using excel uploading operation having date data.
When I upload excel with date 17-Oct-2012 and I am getting 41199.

Comment: can you please post your code whatever you have tried?

Comment: There may be lots of threads available in SO regarding DataTime Formatting. How this one differ from them. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the date format from OLE Automation to the .net format by using DateTime.FromOADate.

```
double doubleValue = double.Parse(b);
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.FromOADate(doubleValue );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static DateTime FromExcelSerialDate(int serialDate){return new DateTime(1899, 12, 31).AddDays(serialDate);}
```

Or other ways from old issues;

[How do I convert an Excel serial date number to a .NET DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727466/how-do-i-convert-an-excel-serial-date-number-to-a-net-datetime)