# How to convert numbers (3939344687) to date vrom excel in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I try to get a value from excel and to use in vb.bet but when i try to convert date from Excel my vba display error.

I try this:

```
Dim Target As DateTime = Nothing
Target = DateTime.ParseExact(currentWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 19).Text, "dd-MMM-yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This code `currentWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 19).Text` get me 3939344687 value from Excel, my date in excel are 01/26/17.

When i try to convert this number to date i get error.

Another code what i try are :

```
Target = Convert.ToDateTime(currentWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 19).Text)
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: How do you know the date is `01/26/17`, how does it look in Excel, and is there a reason you are using `Text` instead of `Value`?

Comment: In Unix time `3939344687` = Sun, 31 Oct 2094 06:24:47 GMT

Comment: Make sure every time you read/save date, it's always in a date object and never as a string. Make sure the excel cells are set to be dates.

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727466/how-do-i-convert-an-excel-serial-date-number-to-a-net-datetime . But your date should look like this: `42761`