# How to convert a formula date C# before populate datagridview

Tags: c#, date, datagridview, format

Hello everyone I have a date format like this: 47028 and I would like to convert it to the format yyyy / MM / dd for example.
Before inserting it into a datagridview.

I try this:

```
if (blablabla)
                    {
                        string str = "47028";
                        DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }
```

but of course it does not work ...

it is a conversion that I wish to make but I do not find how.

Comment: what date should the result be after if we take 47028 as an input?

Comment: @Tommy 02/10/2018 but it will change

Comment: What is that number describing? There is a [`DateTime` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) taking ticks, that is, quote from the documentation, "number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar". Maybe you can somehow calculate the ticks from your number and use that constructor?

Comment: It is not clear how you get the date “02/10/2018” from “47028”. I am confident the posted code is going to fail with a “format exception” saying something similar to: “the string is not in the correct format.” Again, it is unclear how the date conversion is handled and the current code will fail with the string “47028”. In addition, it does not appear the code is “capturing” the parse. The code executes the parse but never gets the returned `DateTime` object. I am guessing you may want to capture the parse.

Comment: Ok I just understand that come from an excel format ..
Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations. By default, January 1, 1900 has serial number 1 and January 1, 2008 has serial number 39448 because this date is 39,448 days after January 1, 1900.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plethora of questions and answers about this… [How do I convert an Excel serial date number to a .NET DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727466/how-do-i-convert-an-excel-serial-date-number-to-a-net-datetime) … The `DateTime` class has a property just for this… `DateTime.FromOADate`. This takes a double and performs the added days as you describe. Example:

```
DateTime.FromOADate(39448).ToLongDateString());
```

The above code will return the string “Tuesday, January 01, 2008”.

This appears to be what you want, however… it may be incorrect. If you look at some of the answers in the above link, you will see that there may be an issue with excel/lotus… whatever. The point is that my calculation puts the date at Thursday, January 03, 2008. My assumption is based on the code below.

Below, a new `DateTime` object `inDate` is created with a date of “01/01/1900.” Then a new `DateTime` object `CalculatedDate` is created by adding 39,448 days to `inDate`. This will result in the date `Thursday, January 03, 2008`. I am confident this is related to leap years. Therefore, pick your own poison. ;-)

```
double totDays = 39448;
DateTime inDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
DateTime CalculatedDate = inDate.AddDays(totDays);
Console.WriteLine(" Start date: " + inDate.ToLongDateString());
Console.WriteLine("   Add days: " + totDays);
Console.WriteLine("Result date: " + CalculatedDate.ToLongDateString());
Console.WriteLine(" FromOADate: " + DateTime.FromOADate(totDays).ToLongDateString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer !