# Why does "N" shows up in Excel report from SQL Server data?

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel, date-formatting, nvarchar

I'm modifying a report that uses SQL Server to export data from package software (Yardi Voyager) into an MS Excel template. The data mostly comes over fine.

However on a few date fields the letter "N" is appended to the imported data and displayed in the cell in Excel.
(This is NOT `#N/A` - just `"N"`)

For example, `FORMAT(tbl.dtStart, 'dd/MM/yyyy')`  returns `31/01/2022` in interactive SQL, which is correct, but the value appearing in the Excel cell is: `31/01/2022N`

Same for `FORMAT(tbl.dtStart, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-AU')`

What I WANT is the usual number of days since 1/1/1900. (And then I'll format it in EXCEL) This value is needed for use in the next step in Excel.

```
CONVERT(Varchar, tbl.dtStart, 103)
```

will display `31/01/2022` correctly (no `'N'`) but is text only - not the number of days needed for the next step in Excel

I expect that this has *something* to do with how MS handles international characters and uses the prefix 'N' for NVARCHAR. But in all the research I've done I can not figure out how to simply eliminate the 'N' and get the number-date.

I suppose it could be something to do with the package software as well, but that would be strange.

I should also note that I have seen this on at least one text field as well - The letter "N" appended to the text value.

As I mentioned, I am *modifying* an existing report. The original code used

```
FORMAT(tbl.dtStart, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

successfully without any `N`. When I modified those lines the "N" began appearing.

Would greatly appreciate replies on how to export the date-number from SQL Server to Excel without the "N".

Comment: `What I WANT is the usual number of days since 1/1/1900  ... then I'll format it in EXCEL`. Note the Excel has a _quirk_ (not exactly a bug, since it's "by design") where [the number of days is wrong before day 59.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/727495/3043)

Comment: Its going to be a quirk of `Yardi Voyager`? Nothing in SQL Server causes that... so probably best to contact product support...